# play stored .avi files in asp.net c# web page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have used asp.net C# (4.0) VS 2010.
I have **.avi** video file already stored in my source.
I want to play that video on page load.

I already tried with **Google** too many times but not satisfied with results.
I need step by step solution to follow.
Anything that i have to import or else that i want to know?

I can play video using you-tube links but i don't want to do that.

I already tried with

```
    string path = "MYFILE.avi";
    Page.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<video width='320' height='240' controls='controls'><source src=" + path + " type='video/avi'></video>"));
```

But this gives me following error

```
No video with supported format and MIME type found
```

Please help.

Comment: PLEASE VISIT THIS LINK:

[link](http://www.templatemonster.com/help/how-to-embed-video-into-html-page.html)

I HAVE TRIED ALL THREE OPTIONS BUT VIDEO IS NOT SHOWING/PLAYING

Answer (score 0):

This relates to this question here on SO: [Does HTML5 <video> playback support the .avi format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4129674/does-html5-video-playback-support-the-avi-format)

Reading up on it via the links in that question you'll see that the only formats that is talked about is WebM, MP4/H264 and Ogg/Theora. There is currently (as far as I know) no browser that supports playing .avi-files with the video-tagg. Either convert it to one of the supported formats or use the embed-tag to include it (though that is a really old way to do it. You can read about that here: http://www.templatemonster.com/help/how-to-embed-video-into-html-page.html

Comment: I HAVE USED THIS CODE BUT VIDEO IS NOT PALYING..
 I AM GETTING BLANK SCREEN


<iframe  width="425" height="349" src="video_URL"  frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

Answer (score 0):

This is not a C# or Asp.net question, it is HTML/HTML5 problem.

I can easily say DON'T use AVI because it is not cross-platform, but I don't know what is your situation.

You can Try :

```
<embed type="video/x-msvideo" src="MYFILE.AVI" autoplay="false" autostart="false" width="600" height="420">
```

and you should try your existing solution with FireFox or Chrome also it may works,

The funniest joke that WAV and AVI are proprietary for Microsoft, but IE does not recognize wav and AVI with HTML5 while other browsers does. I have tried WAV but not AVI.

and you can make a generic solution such:

```
if (browser = ie) then
<embed ...
else
<video width='320' height='240' ...
end if
```

Comment: I tried code from this [link](http://www.dotnetspider.com/forum/285295-Play-video-my-.net-page.aspx)
With .flv file but still its not playing.
And i am using mozilla firefox.
Thanks in advance