# How to play video .avi or .wmv on HTML5 in all OS(Linux,Windows and Mac)

Tags: html

I have some files in format .avi and .wmv, but is imposible play on HTML5 for the codecs, How to play those files on any WebPage on all OS?

Comment: Won't be easy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4129674/does-html5-video-playback-support-the-avi-format?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't according to [W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp) there are only 3 supported video formats: MP4, WebM, and Ogg. You could convert your video files.

Comment: just a side note that w3schools is not a standard.