# Linking to local video file for video background HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, video, background, html5-video

I've been stuck trying to make a video on my computer be the video in the background. My video is titled "runbg.avi" and it is in the same folder as my HTML and CSS files.

These are a couple of many websites that I visited to search for an answer.

[Using file:// instead of http:// when trying to get video from my computer rather than the web.](http://www.overclock.net/t/1249732/css-background-image-using-local-file)

[I can point to video on the web but not locally.](https://slicejack.com/fullscreen-html5-video-background-css/)

My program so far.

```css
/* BACKGROUND */
video#vid {
position: fixed; 
right: 0; 
bottom: 0;
min-width: 100%; 
min-height: 100%;
width: auto; 
height: auto; 
z-index: -100;
background-size: cover;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Seb's Fitness</title>

<link rel = "stylesheet"
      type = "text/css"
      href = "css.css" />

      <video autoplay loop poster="" id="vid">
    <source src="file://runbg.avi" type="video/avi">
    </video>
```

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: How do I link to a local video file?

Comment: Do you miss the <body> element??

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: HTML5 video tag does not support AVI video types

You can use online video converter tool to convert to supported video type.
MP4, OGG, WEBM

[Does HTML5 <video> playback support the .avi format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4129674/does-html5-video-playback-support-the-avi-format)

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4129674/does-html5-video-playback-support-the-avi-format)
HTML5 video tag does not support AVI. Must use MP4, OGG, or WEBM

Comment: Thanks! I was stumped for so long.

Answer (score 0):

```
<video autoplay loop poster="" id="vid">
    <source src="/runbg.avi" type="video/avi">
 </video>
```

/runbg.avi means start in the root folder (/) and then search runbh.avi file.

learn more [relative and absolute paths](http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/)

Comment: If this doesn't work for you then the html and .avi file aren't in the same folder. Please let me know your folder structure to help you.